# Exploding specific type of json, into columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So i have the following sample json, contained into a series of mine

```
s = pd.Series(['{"city":"Uberlândia","bot-origin":null,"campaign-source":"carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms","lastState":"productAvailabilityCepInDatabaseEqualTrue","main-installation-date":null,"userid":"01bb36b9-632c-4cdb-8cd7-2a5b108fa558@tunnel.msging.net","full-name":null,"alternative-installation-date":null,"chosen-product":"Internet","bank":null,"postalcode":"38405328","due-date":null,"cpf":"01548226041","origin-link":"","payment":null,"state":"MG","api-orders-hash-id":null,"email":null,"api-orders-error":null,"plan-name":null,"userphone":"34 9342-8011","plan-offer":null,"completed-address":"38405328 - R IGUACU, 1289 - UMUARAMA - null - Uberlândia - MG","type-of-person":"CPF","onboarding-simplified":null,"type-of-product":"Residencial","main-installation-period-day":null,"plan-value":null,"alternative-installation-period-day":null,"data-change":"false"}',
       '{"city":"Uberlândia","bot-origin":null,"campaign-source":"carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms","lastState":"productAvailabilityCepInDatabaseEqualTrue","main-installation-date":null,"userid":"01bb36b9-632c-4cdb-8cd7-2a5b108fa558@tunnel.msging.net","full-name":null,"alternative-installation-date":null,"chosen-product":"Internet","bank":null,"postalcode":"38405328","due-date":null,"cpf":"01548226041","origin-link":"","payment":null,"state":"MG","api-orders-hash-id":null,"email":null,"api-orders-error":null,"plan-name":null,"userphone":"34 9342-8011","plan-offer":null,"completed-address":"38405328 - R IGUACU, 1289 - UMUARAMA - null - Uberlândia - MG","type-of-person":"CPF","onboarding-simplified":null,"type-of-product":"Residencial","main-installation-period-day":null,"plan-value":null,"alternative-installation-period-day":null,"data-change":"false"}',
       '{"city":"Uberlândia","bot-origin":null,"campaign-source":"carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms","lastState":"productAvailabilityAddressConfirmation","main-installation-date":null,"userid":"01bb36b9-632c-4cdb-8cd7-2a5b108fa558@tunnel.msging.net","full-name":null,"alternative-installation-date":null,"chosen-product":"Internet","bank":null,"postalcode":"38405328","due-date":null,"cpf":"01548226041","origin-link":"","payment":null,"state":"MG","api-orders-hash-id":null,"email":null,"api-orders-error":null,"plan-name":null,"userphone":"34 9342-8011","plan-offer":null,"completed-address":"38405328 - R IGUACU, 1289 - UMUARAMA - null - Uberlândia - MG","type-of-person":"CPF","onboarding-simplified":null,"type-of-product":"Residencial","main-installation-period-day":null,"plan-value":null,"alternative-installation-period-day":null,"data-change":"false"}'])
```

I dont actually know a way of exploding this type of json, into columns, would appreciate some help? I tried json_normalize loads and so on but i get empty results.

Wanted result would be something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'city':['Uberlandia','Uberlandia','Uberlandia'],'bot-origin':[null,null,null]}) # There are more columns but you get the jist.
```

Since there were a lot of answers would appreciate if someone showed me the most time efficient way, have lots of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(s.map(json.loads))
print(df)
```

only printed a part of the whole df for presentation.

```
         city bot-origin                    campaign-source                                  lastState main-installation-date
0  Uberlândia       None  carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms  productAvailabilityCepInDatabaseEqualTrue                   None
1  Uberlândia       None  carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms  productAvailabilityCepInDatabaseEqualTrue                   None
2  Uberlândia       None  carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms     productAvailabilityAddressConfirmation                   None
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
import json 

s = pd.Series(['{"city":"Uberlândia","bot-origin":null,"campaign-source":"carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms","lastState":"productAvailabilityCepInDatabaseEqualTrue","main-installation-date":null,"userid":"01bb36b9-632c-4cdb-8cd7-2a5b108fa558@tunnel.msging.net","full-name":null,"alternative-installation-date":null,"chosen-product":"Internet","bank":null,"postalcode":"38405328","due-date":null,"cpf":"01548226041","origin-link":"","payment":null,"state":"MG","api-orders-hash-id":null,"email":null,"api-orders-error":null,"plan-name":null,"userphone":"34 9342-8011","plan-offer":null,"completed-address":"38405328 - R IGUACU, 1289 - UMUARAMA - null - Uberlândia - MG","type-of-person":"CPF","onboarding-simplified":null,"type-of-product":"Residencial","main-installation-period-day":null,"plan-value":null,"alternative-installation-period-day":null,"data-change":"false"}',
       '{"city":"Uberlândia","bot-origin":null,"campaign-source":"carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms","lastState":"productAvailabilityCepInDatabaseEqualTrue","main-installation-date":null,"userid":"01bb36b9-632c-4cdb-8cd7-2a5b108fa558@tunnel.msging.net","full-name":null,"alternative-installation-date":null,"chosen-product":"Internet","bank":null,"postalcode":"38405328","due-date":null,"cpf":"01548226041","origin-link":"","payment":null,"state":"MG","api-orders-hash-id":null,"email":null,"api-orders-error":null,"plan-name":null,"userphone":"34 9342-8011","plan-offer":null,"completed-address":"38405328 - R IGUACU, 1289 - UMUARAMA - null - Uberlândia - MG","type-of-person":"CPF","onboarding-simplified":null,"type-of-product":"Residencial","main-installation-period-day":null,"plan-value":null,"alternative-installation-period-day":null,"data-change":"false"}',
       '{"city":"Uberlândia","bot-origin":null,"campaign-source":"carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms","lastState":"productAvailabilityAddressConfirmation","main-installation-date":null,"userid":"01bb36b9-632c-4cdb-8cd7-2a5b108fa558@tunnel.msging.net","full-name":null,"alternative-installation-date":null,"chosen-product":"Internet","bank":null,"postalcode":"38405328","due-date":null,"cpf":"01548226041","origin-link":"","payment":null,"state":"MG","api-orders-hash-id":null,"email":null,"api-orders-error":null,"plan-name":null,"userphone":"34 9342-8011","plan-offer":null,"completed-address":"38405328 - R IGUACU, 1289 - UMUARAMA - null - Uberlândia - MG","type-of-person":"CPF","onboarding-simplified":null,"type-of-product":"Residencial","main-installation-period-day":null,"plan-value":null,"alternative-installation-period-day":null,"data-change":"false"}'])

df = s.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(json.loads(row)))
```

Output:

|  | city | bot-origin | campaign-source | lastState | main-installation-date | userid | full-name | alternative-installation-date | chosen-product | bank | postalcode | due-date | cpf | origin-link | payment | state | api-orders-hash-id | email | api-orders-error | plan-name | userphone | plan-offer | completed-address | type-of-person | onboarding-simplified | type-of-product | main-installation-period-day | plan-value | alternative-installation-period-day | data-change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Uberlândia |  | carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms | productAvailabilityCepInDatabaseEqualTrue |  | 01bb36b9-632c-4cdb-8cd7-2a5b108fa558@tunnel.msging.net |  |  | Internet |  | 38405328 |  | 01548226041 |  |  | MG |  |  |  |  | 34 9342-8011 |  | 38405328 - R IGUACU, 1289 - UMUARAMA - null - Uberlândia - MG | CPF |  | Residencial |  |  |  | false |
| 1 | Uberlândia |  | carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms | productAvailabilityCepInDatabaseEqualTrue |  | 01bb36b9-632c-4cdb-8cd7-2a5b108fa558@tunnel.msging.net |  |  | Internet |  | 38405328 |  | 01548226041 |  |  | MG |  |  |  |  | 34 9342-8011 |  | 38405328 - R IGUACU, 1289 - UMUARAMA - null - Uberlândia - MG | CPF |  | Residencial |  |  |  | false |
| 2 | Uberlândia |  | carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms | productAvailabilityAddressConfirmation |  | 01bb36b9-632c-4cdb-8cd7-2a5b108fa558@tunnel.msging.net |  |  | Internet |  | 38405328 |  | 01548226041 |  |  | MG |  |  |  |  | 34 9342-8011 |  | 38405328 - R IGUACU, 1289 - UMUARAMA - null - Uberlândia - MG | CPF |  | Residencial |  |  |  | false |

---

The `null` values are converted to `None`. If you want to convert them to NaN you can use `.fillna(np.nan)`:

```
import json
import numpy as np

df = (
    s.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(json.loads(row)))
     .fillna(np.nan)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have `string` formatted json objects, first we need to convert them then pass them into a `json_normalize` method.

```
import json 

df1 = pd.json_normalize(s.map(json.loads))


         city bot-origin                    campaign-source                                  lastState  ... main-installation-period-day plan-value alternative-installation-period-day data-change
0  Uberlândia       None  carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms  productAvailabilityCepInDatabaseEqualTrue  ...                         None       None                                None       false
1  Uberlândia       None  carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms  productAvailabilityCepInDatabaseEqualTrue  ...                         None       None                                None       false
2  Uberlândia       None  carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms     productAvailabilityAddressConfirmation  ...                         None       None                                None       false
```